# Loop within a loop, Creating a top X list

Tags: for-loop

I have the function below to output top 5 restaurants results based on rating. **How do I add a for loop in this loop so that the output includes the position in the top 5?**

```
def print_top_5(restaurant_list):
    sorted_list = sorted(restaurant_list, key = itemgetter("rating"),reverse = True)
    for restaurant in sorted_list[:5]:
        print restaurant["name"]
        print restaurant["rating"]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Python's built-in `enumerate` function:

```
def print_top_5(restaurant_list):
    sorted_list = sorted(restaurant_list, key = itemgetter("rating"),reverse = True)
    for idx, restaurant in enumerate(sorted_list[:5]):
        print(idx, restaurant["name"], restaurant["rating"])
```

Note this counts up starting from 0, so your output will looking something like:

```
0 Restaurant 1 10
1 Restaurant 2 9
2 Restaurant 3 8.5
```

If you'd like the count to start at 1, just add 1 to `idx`:

```
print(idx+1, restaurant["name"], restaurant["rating"])
```